# Uzula enigado por la teksta ludo

Tags: programming

Kiel ekskribi kodo de uzula enigado en C++? Tiu devas funkcii tiel, por depost la enigado povos ankaŭfoje enigi. Tio estas:

> Enigu io
>
> > Preni pomo

> Pomo prenis

> > Rigardi en fenestron
> > En fenestron vidas suno.

En ideo, tiu estas ciklo **while**, kiu estas kontroli tio, ke enigis la uzulo. T.e:

```
int ludeto = 1;

void fu_enigado() {
  std::string u_enigado;
  std::cin >> u_enigado;
  
  <...> // ?
}

void LudStato() {
  while(ludeto == 1) {
    switch(ludeto) {
      case 0:
        exit(1);
        break;
      case 1:
        void fu_enigado();
        break;
    };
  };
}

int main() {
  void LudStato()
  return 0;
}
```

Sed tiu kodo ne funkcias kiel bezone.

Comment: Bonvenon al StackExchange. Mi ne certas ĉu mi bone komprenas la demandon. Ĉu vi demandas pri programado en C++? Atentu ke ĉi tiu retejo estas por demandi pri la lingvo Esperanto, ne por demandi teknikajn aferojn pri programado. Ĝi ne estas esperantlingva versio de StackOverflow. Parenteze se vi kreas tekstaventuron eble interesus vin ĉi tiu ilo https://github.com/Esperanto/aventuro/blob/main/dokumentoj/kreu-ludon.md

Comment: Ho, mi ne scias, ke tiuĉi retejo ne estas eo-versio de stackoverflow. Dankon, ke vi sciigas min pri tia aĵo.